# PHP: How to update a variable of a parent class from a child class

Tags: php, class, variables, parent

I have a function in a child class which counts the number of SQL queries in a page load

In the child class which extends the parent class, after every: `mysql_query($query);`

I put `parent::update_query_function();`

where `update_query_function()` is:

```
function update_query_function(){

$this->query_num++;

}
```

**the `$query_num` variable in the parent class is not being updated. Why?**

Comment: Just a quick thought - I might be wrong - but if you have multiple instantiations of the child class, won't they each have a separate instantiation of the parent class and therefore a separate query count. Does that affect what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It would do - yes. I need one concrete number for the total query count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your child class extends the parent class there's no need to do that, do this instead:

```
$this->update_query_function();
```

that's the point of inheritance.