# How to update a parent constructor variable in BOTH child classes when one child class updates value of constructor variable?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

First off, I believe my question is different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786620/php-how-to-update-a-variable-of-a-parent-class-from-a-child-class).

I have written my own framework for an application I am working on ***but I keep encountering 1 specific (IMO, minor) architectural issue for which I believe there should be a better solution***.

Suppose two classes inherit from a single parent:

```
class AAA {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->go_between = __CLASS__;
    }
    // many other methods in here which BBB and CCC require
}

class BBB extends AAA {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function mutatorBBB() {
        $this->go_between = __CLASS__;
    }
}

class CCC extends AAA {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function returnValue() {
        return $this->go_between;
    }
}
```

Now suppose you need a "go_between" variable in both `BBB` and `CCC` because somewhere in `BBB`, you must use methods in `CCC`, i.e.,

```
$CCC = new CCC(); // somewhere in class BBB so the methods of CCC can be used
```

So if you run the following code in your index:

```
$BBB = new BBB();
$CCC = new CCC();

echo $BBB->go_between;
echo "\n";
echo $CCC->go_between;
```

the following **expected** output is generated:

```
AAA
AAA
```

However, suppose you update the value of the "go-between" constructor variable in one of the child classes:

```
$BBB->mutatorBBB();
echo $BBB->go_between;
echo "\n";
echo $CCC->returnValue();
```

In this case, the following output is generated:

```
BBB // mutatorBBB() updated the value of $this->go_between
AAA // Why doesn't class CCC "see" the updated value of the go-between variable? That is, why doesn't CCC "see" the value as updated by mutatorBBB()? (that is ----> 'BBB')
```

I am able to get past this easily, but I do not believe this is "best practice":

```
class Common {
    static $go_between; // initialize
}
```

Now re-factor the classes slightly:

```
class AAA {
    public function __construct() {
        Common::$go_between = __CLASS__;
    }
    // many other methods in here which BBB and CCC require
}

class BBB extends AAA {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function mutatorBBB() {
        Common::$go_between = __CLASS__;
    }
}

class CCC extends AAA {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function returnValue() {
        return Common::$go_between;
    }
}
```

Now the output of the following:

```
$BBB->mutatorBBB();
echo Common::$go_between;
echo "\n";
echo $CCC->returnValue();
```

is this (i.e., the desired outcome for my application):

```
BBB
BBB
```

I have repeatedly had to retreat back to a `static` class in the global namespace to accomplish this.

*Is there a more "object-oriented" way to update a go-between variable from a parent constructor in use by 2 child classes in which one child instantiates and needs the second child class?*

Comment: `$BBB` and `$CCC` inherit the values from the parent when they're instantiated; after which point in time they're totally separate objects - altering a property of one won't affect the other even if that property is inherited from the parent. In most cases this is what you'd want; `Dog` and `Cat` might both inherit the `numberOfLegs` property from `Mammal` but, *Unlucky Hubert* the Dachshund (a `Dog` object) lost a leg when playing in traffic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a communication channel between two instances, that channel should be a separate object.

> You should prefer composition over inheritance.

Kinda like this:

```
$channel = new Channel;
$foo = new Foo($channel);
$bar = new Bar($channel);

$foo->writeToChannel('aaa');
echo $bar->readFromChannel();
```

Live example here: https://3v4l.org/burHd

Comment: Nice solution - I will say my "hack" solution is quicker (to implement), but would you consider it "bad" practice? I want to code more cleanly but unsure of downsides of my solution

Comment: OK, thanks - makes sense. Plus I have to worry about over populating the global namespace, which has made my variable names increasingly lengthy and "creative"

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob you should always focus on making the code easier to understand. You spend a lot more time reading and editing old code, than **writing** new.